# The definition of convex body and the Hilbert cube

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I currently have a question about the definition of convex body. The formal definition is: a convex body is a convex set which has non-empty interior. By non-empty interior, we meant for a set $N\subset M$, a point $x\in N$, and any points $y\in M$, $\exists\  \epsilon=\epsilon(y)$ such that $x + ty \in N$ for $|t|< \epsilon$. I think the definition should state that $|t|>0$ as well.

The reason I asked this question is because I was trying to prove that the Hilbert Cube is a convex set but not convex body. After proving it a convex set, and using contradiction to prove the latter part, I ended up with the case that if the Hilbert Cube is a convex body, then $t=0$ is the only value that may satisfy $x + ty\in$ Hilbert Cube. This is immediately a contradiction to the "new" definition I had above, since $|t|> 0$. I wonder if this is a valid conclusion to make?

Answer (score 1):

> ended up with the case that if the Hilbert Cube is a convex body, then $t=0$ is the only value that may satisfy $x + ty\in$ Hilbert Cube

This is not a complete statement without quantifiers on $x, y$. Did you mean: For all $x,y$? For some $x,y$? For all $x$ and some $y$ dependent on $x$? Etc.

Here's a precise statement you can prove: there is $y$ such that for every $x\in C$ ($C$ being the Hilbert cube) $x+ty\notin C$ for $t\ne 0$. (This implies that $x$ is not an interior point.) I'll give you a hint: $y$ can be chosen to be the sequence $y_k=1/k^{2/3}$.

> By non-empty interior, we meant for a set $N\subset M$, a point $x\in N$, and any points $y\in M$, $\exists\  \epsilon=\epsilon(y)$ such that $x + ty \in N$ for $|t|< \epsilon$.

This is an odd way to talk about nonempty interior. Maybe you confused the definition with a consequence of having nonempty interior? Normally, $x$ is an interior point if some open ball centered at $x$ is contained in the set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed comment. I meant for all $x$ and some $y$ in $l^{2}$. So, basically, I chose the point $y=(1,\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3},...)$, which belongs to $l^{2}$, and showed that the only value that may keep $x+ty$ in the Hilbert cube is when $t=0$. This leads to contradiction due to the alternative definition I made, which requires $|t|>0$. My question was: is this a valid contradiction, because I think it's equivalent to say that $$ (Hilbert cube in this case) has empty-interior?

Comment: According to the definition of [Hilbert cube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_cube), your $y$ does not do the job: $0+ty$ is in the cube for all $|t|<1$.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't, because that's what I want to show (a Hilbert Cube is NOT a convex body). Btw, this is an example from "Introductory Real Analysis" by Fomin. That's why it leads to a contradiction at the end ($t=0$ is the only choice for $x+ty$ is in the cube). Actually, your example shows that I chose the correct point to lead to a conclusion that "Hilbert cube is not a convex body."

Comment: do you think my arrival at contradiction above is valid because of the fact that $t=0$ is the only choice for $x+ty$ is in the cube?